# Convert .Net 4.8 EF6 SQL Server webapi project to AWS RDS Aurora MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, amazon-aurora, .net-4.8

I developed locally using SQL Server and am attempting to get it working in AWS.

I installed the "AWS Toolkit for VS2019" and published to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I modified the code to grab the connection properties as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html

I also created the database and populated it with data.

I loaded the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql NuGet package.

When I call a test "Hello World" api function it returns Hello World.

When I attempt to call a function that accesses the database the first error I get is

> Keyword Data Source not expected in the connection string.

If I refresh the browser I get this next error

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
> disposed.

I'm not sure what the provider and providerName sections should be or how it should be set using AppSettings to determine the connection string.

```
public static class RDS_Helper
{
    public static string GetRDSConnectionString()
    {
        var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        string dbname = appConfig["RDS_DB_NAME"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbname)) return null;

        string username = appConfig["RDS_USERNAME"];
        string password = appConfig["RDS_PASSWORD"];
        string hostname = appConfig["RDS_HOSTNAME"];
        string port = appConfig["RDS_PORT"];
        //return $"data source={hostname}:{port};initial catalog={dbname};persist security info=True;user id={username};password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;";
        return $"metadata=res://*/MyContext.csdl|res://*/MyContext.ssdl|res://*/MyContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={hostname}:{port};initial catalog={dbname};persist security info=True;user id={username};password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
    }
}
```

and here's where I'm creating the context:

```
public static class Conn
{
    private static MyData.MyContext _db;
    public static MyData.MyContext db
    {
        get
        {
            if (_db == null) _db = new MyContext(RDS_Helper.GetRDSConnectionString());
            // providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
            return _db;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone direct me to a sample project or instructions regarding creation of a .Net project with Entity Framework using an AWS RDS datasource?   Or maybe some direction on what to try next?  and/or what values should be used for Provider and ProviderName?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It is easier to get the connection string correct if you use the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder

Comment: The connection string the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder created was slightly different.  I used that value and now I get the error:  Keyword not supported: 'port'.

Comment: I moved port to the server=MyServer:3306 and now I get another error.  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development. This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project.

Comment: I'm going through this page now:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: No change.  after going through that web page I made some adjustments to provider and provider names and loaded another nuget package for MySql.Data.EntityFramework but am still getting the same error of UnintentionalCodeFirstException.  Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sarcasm>
I'm amazed at how many people stepped up to the plate to try to help me with this problem.
</sarcasm>
```

Here's how to convert a SQL Server Entity Framework project to MySQL -- **Don't.**

Instead follow these steps:

1. Install MySQL for Visual Studio
2. Create a new .Net Class library project
3. Install NuGet package of "MySql.Data.EntityFramework"
4. Create a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to this project using "MySql Database" as a data-source (which should appear when you create a connection to your database